# users reporting recaptcha not appearing MVC

Tags: recaptcha

I published a web site: "https://www.mynotefy.com". Some users were not able to see the recaptcha screen on createaccount pageon chrome browsers.

Any reason why this is happening. No errors are being logged.

"if we use https in chrome, recaptcha not showing. If we use just http, recaptcha is showing".
How do we fix this issue ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the warnings I get in the Console of Chrome Developer Tools:

```
[blocked] The page at https://www.mynotefy.com/Account/CreateAccount ran insecure content from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Istok+Web:400,700,400italic,700italic|Rokkitt:400,700.
[blocked] The page at https://www.mynotefy.com/Account/CreateAccount ran insecure content from http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Lci-doSAAAAAHuBYSQjNhr-qgvdqkXuVqn7OtS3.
```

My guess is that your page is an `HTTPS` and these links are `HTTP`, so that's why they are being blocked.

Comment: PS I don't see the recaptcha either.